# Why am i getting this out put?

Tags: c++

I've been working on this program for a very long time now and I think I'm close to being done. However, my code is outputting something strange and I cannot find the issue.

#### Expected output:

> This is a happy tESt to check if my reader works!
>   An happy alligator was AT tHe happy park and a happy a cow blew its nose in a happy scarf. are you an happy Octagon THe

#### Actual output:

> This is a tE happySt to check if my reader works!
>   a happy
>   THe Happy

How can I make the following code behave as I expect?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

void
usage(char *progname, string msg){
    cerr << "Error: " << msg << endl;
    cerr << "Usage is: " << progname << " [filename]" << endl;
    cerr << " specifying filename reads from that file; no filename reads standard input" << endl;
}
string capitalization(string word,string adj){
    for(int i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++){
        if(isupper(word[i])){
            for(int j = 0; j <= adj.length(); j++){
                adj[j] = toupper(adj[j]);
                return adj;
            }
        }
        else if(isupper(word[0])){
            for(int j = 0; j <= adj.length(); j++){
                adj[j] = tolower(adj[j]);
                return adj;
            }
        }
        else{
            for(int j = 0; j <= adj.length(); j++){
                adj[j] = tolower(adj[j]);
                return adj;
            }
        }
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        string adj;
        string file;
        cin >> adj;
        cin >> file;
        string line;
        string articles[14] = {"a","A","an","aN","An","AN","the","The","tHe","thE","THe","tHE","ThE","THE"};
        ifstream rfile;
        rfile.open(file.c_str());
        if(rfile.fail()){
            cerr << "Error while attempting to open the file." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        string::size_type pos;
        string word;
        string words[1024];
        while(getline(rfile,line)){
            istringstream iss(line);
            for(int i = 0; i <= line.length(); i++){
                iss >> word;
                words[i] = word;
                for(int j = 0; j <= 14; j++){
                    if(word == articles[j]){
                        string article = word;
                        iss >> word;
                        pos = line.find(article);
                        //cout << pos << endl;
                        string adjec = capitalization(word,adj);
                        int position = (pos + word.length());
                        line.insert(position, " " + adjec);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        cout << line << "\n";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not fix any of your problems, but...

The logic in these lines is wrong.

```
       istringstream iss(line);
        for(int i = 0; i <= line.length(); i++){
            iss >> word;
```

Let's say your line is

```
This is a test.
```

For this line, `line.length()` is 15 but there aren't 15 words. What you need is

```
        istringstream iss(line);
        while ( iss >> word ) {
```